# html <object> does not get rendered in 100% height

Tags: html, css, object, innerhtml

**Application description**

I have a web page that has a `title` and a `menu bar` across the top, the rest is for the `content`. The `menu bar` is sticky while the `content` scrolls. When a menu item is clicked, the objective is to open a page in the `content` at full width and height. Currently, the height shows only 8 lines after the `loadPage` script is executed. I've tried various solutions from `stackoverflow` and `Google` but nothing worked. I've tried `iframe` solution but it did not extend to 100% width and/or 100% height.

Please Help! Thanks in advance.

```js
function loadPage(docName) {
  if (!document.getElementById("mainFrame"))
    return false;
  document.getElementById("mainFrame").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" width="100%" heigth="100%" data="' + docName + '"></object>';
}
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "0px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "30px";
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100% width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#titleFrame {
  /* Welcome to the CyberPlaypen */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: navy;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 54px;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleFrame">Welcome to the CyberPlaypen</div>
<div id="navbar" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Labs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ctfest">CTFest</a></li>
    <li><a href="#training">CodeFest</a></li>
    <li><a href="#powershack" onclick="loadPage('CyberPlaypenDoc.html');">PowerShack</a></li>
    <li><a href="#toolsoft">ToolSoft</a></li>
    <li><a href="#training">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainFrame">
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... just figured it out, logged back in to delete - am glad that you responded. The only ugliness is if the window is resized, I get 2 vertical scroll bars, one for object and one for the document.... if you have any suggest on having on one scroll bar please comment. I will continue working at it...

Answer (score 0):

you need set the height to `mainFrame` and `object tag`

```
#mainFrame {
    height: 100%; 
}

#mainFrame object {
    height: 100%; 
}
```

---

*Example*

```js
function loadPage(docName) {
  if (!document.getElementById("mainFrame"))
    return false;
  document.getElementById("mainFrame").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" width="100%" heigth="100%" data="' + docName + '"></object>';
}
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "0px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginTop = "30px";
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* new */
#mainFrame {
    height: 100%;
}

#mainFrame object {
    height: 100%;
}

/* original */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100% width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#titleFrame {
  /* Welcome to the CyberPlaypen */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: navy;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 54px;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleFrame">Welcome to the CyberPlaypen</div>
<div id="navbar" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Labs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ctfest">CTFest</a></li>
    <li><a href="#training">CodeFest</a></li>
    <li><a href="#powershack" onclick="loadPage('https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki');">PowerShack</a></li>
    <li><a href="#toolsoft">ToolSoft</a></li>
    <li><a href="#training">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainFrame">
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
</div>
```